# Redirect RegEx interferes with WordPress pagination

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I converted a Drupal site to WordPress and am using the [Redirection plugin](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/) to redirect the old page hierarchy to the new one.

I need to get **example.com/page/slug** to go to **example.com/slug**. I used /page/(.*), but that breaks the pagination in WordPress since it uses /category/category-name/page/2 for it's hierarchy. I get urls like example.com/category/category-name/2 instead.

What's the RegEx I need to get both the pagination and the URL redirects to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `mod_rewrite` syntax, anchor your regex:

```
^page/(.*)
```

... this way the `category/category-name/page/2` would not match anymore.

NB: to my knowledge a leading slash is not necessary when matching URIs with `mod_rewrite`.